# SVG turbulence filter overriding mask

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have a simple SVG element (a circle) with a turbulence and displacement map filter applied, to create a water effect. I also have a mask applied, which hides a portion of the shape. The problem is this: even in an area of the mask which is black, parts of the shape are still shown: the filter causes the image to in some areas expand outside of its normal boundaries, and these areas appear even in the area which should be masked. This issue is only present in Chrome and Chromium, not Firefox. The problem can be seen in action [here](https://sunrise.sugarfi.dev/). The object in question is the bottom red circle - the filter distorts and expands it, and this expanded area shows even in the area which should be masked (the upper half of the screen).

Comment: If you think you've found a Chrome bug, report it to Chrome's bugtracker

Comment: You are right that according to spec [filters should be applied before masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791815/) To work around a bug in a browser, apply the filter effect to the element, then wrap it in a group and apply the mask to that group.

Comment: Issue doesn't occur on Chrome/Mac - so probably a Windows specific, maybe even a GPU specific bug

Comment: I'm running Chromium on OpenSUSE Linux

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *entirely* sure if this is what you're having problems with - but the default filter region is x = -10% width= 120% - so that spillage you're seeing outside your mask is not a bug, it's the default behavior.

Change your filter element to:

```
<filter x="0%" y=0%" width="100%" height="100% .. etc.
```

and see if you get the behavior you're hoping for.